# Calculating values of integrals using Fourier series and uniform convergence

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

I have a problem that I don't know how to begin solving. I have f(t)
$$
f(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2+1}\sin{kt}
$$
First I had to show that this series converges uniformly, I've done that using Weierstrass M-test comparing the series to
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}
$$ 
Then using this result (and possibly Fourier series), I have to solve these 2 integrals
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\sin{3t}dt \qquad \text and \qquad \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos{3t}dt
$$
The problem is that I have no idea how to begin solving this. I tried just sticking $f(t)$ inside these integrals, and then using uniform convergence to swap the integral and sum, but I end up with an integral that I don't know how to solve.

Could i get some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue the answer posted by @JackD'Aurizio, recall that $\sin(nx)\sin(mx)=\frac12(\cos((n-m)x)-\cos((n+m)x))$.  Then, we have

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx=\frac12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos((n-m)x)\,dx-\frac12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos((n+m)x)\,dx$$

For $n=m$

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos((n-m)x)\,dx=2\pi$$

while for $n\ne m$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos((n-m)x)\,dx&=\left.\frac{\sin((n-m)x)}{n-m}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\\\
&=\frac{\sin((n-m)\pi)}{n-m}-\frac{\sin(-(n-m)\pi)}{n-m}\\\\
&=0-0\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Similarly, for $n=-m$

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos((n+m)x)\,dx=2\pi$$

while for $n\ne -m$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos((n+m)x)\,dx&=\left.\frac{\sin((n+m)x)}{n+m}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\\\
&=\frac{\sin((n+m)\pi)}{n+m}-\frac{\sin(-(n+m)\pi)}{n+m}\\\\
&=0-0\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

---

Analogously, recall that $\sin(nx)\cos(mx)=\frac12(\sin((n+m)x)+\sin((n-m)x))$.  Then,

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx=\frac12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin((n+m)x)\,dx-\frac12 \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin((n-m)x))\,dx$$

For $n=-m$

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin((n+m)x)\,dx=0$$

and for $n\ne -m$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin((n+m)x)\,dx&=\left.\frac{-\cos((n+m)x)}{n+m}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\\\
&=\frac{-\cos((n+m)\pi)}{n+m}-\frac{-\cos(-(n+m)\pi)}{n+m}\\\\
&=-(-1)^{n+m}+(-1)^{n+m}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Similarly, for $n=m$

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin((n-m)x)\,dx=0$$

and for $n\ne m$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin((n-m)x)\,dx&=\left.\frac{-\cos((n-m)x)}{n-m}\right|_{-\pi}^{\pi}\\\\
&=\frac{-\cos((n-m)\pi)}{n-m}-\frac{-\cos(-(n-m)\pi)}{n-m}\\\\
&=-(-1)^{n-m}+(-1)^{n-m}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

---

Putting everything together gives

$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\sin(mx)\,dx=
\begin{cases}
\pi,&n=m\\\\
0,&n\ne m
\end{cases}
$$

and

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(nx)\cos(mx)\,dx=0$$

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use the main property (orthogonality) of the Fourier base. Provided that $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$,

$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(ax)\cos(bx)\,dx=0\tag{1}$$
as well as:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(ax)\cos(bx)\,dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(ax)\sin(bx)\,dx= \pi\cdot\delta(a,b)\tag{2} $$
hence your integrals equal $\frac{\pi}{10}$ and $0$ by termwise integration.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've never hear of orthogonality of Fourier base, could you expand your answer?

Comment: @JamMaster: just have a look at http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PeriodicOrthogonal.aspx

Comment: And what does $\delta(a,b)$ mean?

Comment: @JamMaster: the function that equals one if $a=b$ and zero otherwise.